# Raster comes in black square outside my shape layer while performing unsupervised classification in QGIS

Tags: qgis, land-classification

Any idea why my raster comes in black square outside my shape layer while performing unsupervised classification in QGIS? How can I correct this?

[image: UNSUPERVISED CLASSIFICATION IN QGIS]

Tried correcting it by adding 100% transparency for pixel values 0, but, post processing report includes these no data values in calculation of area and pixel sum.

Comment: please specify the algorithm used.

Comment: K means clustering with minimum distance method

Answer (score 0):

The black pixels should be `no data` value.
First inspect the black pixel to know what is its value.
Next,go layer styling/properties and check the `no data value` or fill the `additional no data value` option.

Comment: Black pixel, obviously, have 0 value. wanted to know exactly why the black region has been created, if the clipped bandset was used

Answer (score 0):

The output of your algorithm is a raster image which by definition is a grid with a rectangular shape. The algorithm will create a rectangle as the minimum bounding box of your region of interest and fill the pixels outside this ROI with No Data or any other value you specify.